# How to send a post request using UDP in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, post, udp, udpclient

I am trying to send a POST request using UDP Protocol instead of TCP (used by Http) ,

All I found is how to send packages using UDP but I need to send a POST Request ,

how can I do this ?

Here is the code I used to send a string using UDP :

```
            using (var client = new UdpClient())
            {
                client.EnableBroadcast = true;
                var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 15000);
                var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World - " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                await client.SendAsync(message, message.Length, endpoint);
                client.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Did you mean to say "*I am trying to send a POST request using UDP Protocol not **TCP***" ? and if so, why?

Comment: You are confused.  TCP and UDP are two different in the transport layer on the Internet.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  A POST is HTTP Application layer and not the transport layer (TCP or UDP).  So if you are sending UDP it is not "USUALLY" referred to as a POST.  The UDP message can be any format (binary or string).  So your UDP message can be formatted as html string like a HTTP message.  You then have to parse the html string when it is received.

Comment: @jdweng _"The UDP message can be any format (binary or string)"_ - no, UDP packets only contain bytes. _"So your UDP message can be formatted as html string like a HTTP message"_ - no, HTTP messages are not formatted as HTML strings. _"You then have to parse the html string when it is received"_ - no, web servers do not "parse html strings", whatever that may mean.

Comment: @Maria why do you think you need to do this? Do you have a web server somewhere listening on UDP port 15000?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes , I have a UDP  listener on this Port and I wand to send a request via udp through this port

Comment: @CodeCaster : Everything I said is 1000% percent correct!!!

Comment: @jdweng HTTP/3 (UDP) is being used TODAY and is supported by multiple servers, CDNs and browsers currently (wide-spread adoption is coming very soon).

Comment: @Maria you have an UDP listener on that port. Ok, did you implement that yourself? What exactly is the protocol that listener speaks? Why does it accept HTTP POST messages? We're going to need a lot more information to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @jdweng nothing you said in that comment is true in any way. Please explain what a "UPD message [...] formatted as html string" would look like?

Comment: UDP can contain any data binary or not binary including html.  It is lunacy to say that a string is not bytes.  Html is a string and would look like a message embedded in a HTTP request.

Comment: @CoadeCaster : Words can have different meaning and you are looked at my words only one way.  I can say the I posted a message on a bulletin board.  People over 50 will say I took a thumbtack and posted the message on a wall.  People under 50 will say I posted the message on an electronic webpage.  Both are correct.

Comment: @jdweng you're saying a UDP message can contain binary or string data. It can't, it only contains bytes. And yes, a string can be represented in bytes by encoding it. A little while ago, you claimed that HTTP cannot transport binary data, that you need FTP for that. You appear to be confusing terms yourself.

Comment: I now the terms perfectly.  You are very one-sided.  Bytes is a set that can contains lots of different type data 1) binary 2) ASCII 3) Encoded string 4) UTF-8 5) UTF-7 6) Unicode 7) HTML  You could argue that HTML is a subsest of UTF-8 and I would agree or you can say it is a different class and I would also agree.  But to say a string is not bytes is totally wrong.

Comment: @jdweng _"You could argue that HTML is a subsest of UTF-8 and I would agree"_ - then you would be wrong.

Comment: HTML is UTF-8 with certain characters forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests are just text, so build POST request and send it like You send message.
More about [POST request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST).

Example request:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.example
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 27

field1=value1&field2=value2
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, they talk about UDP which I don't think is even possible.

Comment: HTTP requests are just a text, so you can send text over UDP. So, why impossible?

Comment: Please show how to specifically do a POST in UDP then. It's not possible.

Comment: @Steve What you don't understand? What is POST message? Or that UDP can trannsimt any message?  Of course you must have reciever for such messages, but technically You can format POST message and sent it on any channel.

Comment: You pasted a link to the Mozilla MDN describing POST over HTTP. This is not even slightly applicable to UDP. It's pretty much comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: No, this just makes no sense. HTTP servers listen on TCP ports, not on UDP ports.

Comment: communication layer is not important, HTTP messages are text. So if you format proper message you can send it on any channel. Standard is HTTP but nothing stands in the way of send it on any other protocol. For non standard protocols You must have reciever.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think have sense. Message is message transport is transport. I can send POST over any protocol which can carry text. HTTP server cannot recieve this, of corse, but she can have own reciever

Comment: Yes, it is theoretically possible to talk HTTP over UDP, but there are no (well-known) servers that do this.

Comment: @CodeCaster no, OP ask how to send POST message, not HTTP over UDP. And maybe OP have such server, why not.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not theoretically...being used TODAY.... HTTP/3 is UDP-based and is supported by multiple servers, CDNs and browsers currently.

Comment: @Sushi sending a random HTTP/1.1 formatted (i.e. text-based, plaintext) POST message to an arbitrary UDP listener is _somewhat_ different from setting up an HTTP/2 tunnel through CONNECTing to a TCP server and getting an Alt-Svc record containing an UDP port number in return.

Comment: @CodeCaster You said `...HTTP over UDP, but there are no (well-known)...` The browser you are using right now most likely supports HTTP/3 (not 1 or 2) if it is Chromium-based and these page's content was served by a CDN that supports HTTP/3(UDP). etc... HTTP/UDP usage is in the wild and has been for about 1/2 a year. And there is no TCP in HTTP/3, it is HTTP using UDP, no tunnels, no TCP servers, etc.. so not sure what your comment even means.

Comment: @Sushi I do realise that my claims from the quoted comment is too simplified to be true for all scenarios. I do hope though that you're also seeing the context of the question and answer here.

Comment: @CodeCaster You also stated `....HTTP servers listen on TCP ports, not on UDP ports...`  I understand the question, it is just your TCP comments that not helping IMHO as they are incorrect. Is it a question that needs more context from the OP, maybe, but you can open a UDP connection and send a HTTP-formatted "POST"  to a UDP listener, yes you can (again, does the OP have a listener that can accept it, more details would be needed from them...)

Comment: @Sushi I already admitted that was an oversimplification. When people are talking about "HTTP messages", I still assume they mean plaintext, pre-HTTP/2 messages sent over a TCP connection to an HTTP server. Mea culpa, alright? And yes, of course, you can broadcast anything over UDP that you want. Whether some listener can do something useful with it, is a whole different story...